# How to add a dynamic parameter in Mule4 Select Query

Tags: mulesoft

I have a SELECT query for which the entire WHERE condition is coming from a Java class. How can I use the entire WHERE condition in the SELECT query? This is what I tried:

```
SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE_TABLE WHERE 1=1 #[payload]
```

Here payload is a WHERE clause coming from a Java class: `NAME = VKP AND STATE = PA AND CITY = KOP`

I am getting an error message like *" parameter null was not bound for query select…"*, but I am able to see the payload value coming out from the Java class and in the logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use an expression directly in the query. Instead assign the query in an expression to a variable, then use the variable as the query.

For example something like:

```
    <set-variable value="#['SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE_TABLE WHERE 1=1 ' ++ payload]" name="query" />
    <db:select ...>
        <db:sql>#[vars.query]</db:sql>
    </db:select>
```

Note that you risk having SQL injections vulnerabilities doing this.

Comment: Thanks . It worked . In this approach any way we can avoid SQL injection ?